# Missing FROM clause error

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

The following, rather complicated, query generates the error:

> ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "referee" LINE 14: ... select people.id from referees where people.id = referee.id...

```
select people.id, lower(lastname) as lname from people 
where (interests ~* '$key' or biography ~* '$key'
or exists (select * from authors, articles where 
articles.keywords ~* '$key' and articles.id=authors.article_id
and authors.author_id=people.id)) and not inactive and email is not null
and people.id not in (
select people.id from people, authors where authors.author_id = people.id 
and authors.article_id = $article_id)
and people.id not in (
select people.id from articles, referees where 
people.id = referee_id and refused is null and reported is null and 
editors_decision is null and article_id = articles.id)
and people.id not in (
select people.id from referees where people.id = referee.id and reported is not null
and date_trunc('day', current_timestamp - cast(reported as timestamp)) > 30)
```

The error goes away if the last select sub-clause (i.e from `and people.id not in (` to `timestamp)) > 30)`) is deleted and the error message points to that clause, so that must be where the trouble lies.  But the select sub-clause does have a FROM in it and that FROM refers to the referee table that is allegedly missing.  Moreover, the structure of the select sub-clause seems identical to the one above.

I guess I am missing something obvious, but I can't see what.  Any ideas?

[this is using Postgresql 9.0.3 and is being executed though PHP, hence the variable references that start with $ in the SQL above]

Comment: You might want to start with formatting your query using proper indention - in many cases that already reveals the source of the problem.

Comment: Adding aliases would help, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here ( in your last `not in` block ):

```
where people.id = referee.id
```

I believe this should be :

```
where people.id = referees.id
```

**EDIT: This is how I formatted your query:**

```
select people.id, lower(lastname) as lname 
from people 
where (interests ~* '$key' 
  or biography ~* '$key'
  or exists (
    select * from authors, articles 
    where articles.keywords ~* '$key' 
    and articles.id=authors.article_id
    and authors.author_id=people.id)) 
and not inactive 
and email is not null
and people.id not in (
  select people.id 
  from people, authors 
  where authors.author_id = people.id 
  and authors.article_id = $article_id)
and people.id not in (
  select people.id 
  from articles, referees 
  where people.id = referee_id 
  and refused is null 
  and reported is null 
  and editors_decision is null 
  and article_id = articles.id)
and people.id not in (
  select people.id 
  from referees 
  where people.id = referee.id 
  and reported is not null
  and date_trunc('day', current_timestamp - cast(reported as timestamp)) > 30)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select people.id, lower(lastname) as lname from people 
where (interests ~* '$key' or biography ~* '$key'
or exists (select * from authors, articles where 
articles.keywords ~* '$key' and articles.id=authors.article_id
and authors.author_id=people.id)) and not inactive and email is not null
and people.id not in (
select people.id from people, authors where authors.author_id = people.id 
and authors.article_id = $article_id)
and people.id not in (
select people.id from articles, referees where <---- **FROM clause is missing here**
people.id = referee_id and refused is null and reported is null and 
editors_decision is null and article_id = articles.id)
and people.id not in (
select people.id from referees where people.id = referee.id and reported is not null
and date_trunc('day', current_timestamp - cast(reported as timestamp)) > 30)
```

The sub query missing FROM clause in

```
select people.id from articles, referees where <---- **FROM clause is missing here**
people.id = referee_id and refused is null and reported is null and 
editors_decision is null and article_id = articles.id
```